# Can't read and write bmp

Tags: c, image, bmp

Hy I wanted to read a bmp file into a struct and write it then back but the image is alway black the header is ok. but the pixels get wrong written. I compared the hex values and they are the same until the header is finished. The rest is different and way shorter.

```
typedef uint16_t ImageType;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t size;
    uint16_t additionalFeature;
    uint16_t copy;
    uint32_t offset;

} ImageHeader;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t headerSize;
    int width;
    int height;
    uint16_t colorSpaces;
    uint16_t bitsPerPixel;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t size;
    int verticalResolution;
    int horizontalResolution;
    uint32_t totalColors;
    uint32_t importantColors;
} ImageMetadata;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
} ImageColors;

typedef struct {
    ImageType type;
    ImageHeader header;
    ImageMetadata metadata;
    ImageColors **pixels;
} Image;
```

Here is my image structure. At the moment it is only for a 24 bpp Image later on I want to change it. But my problem is that after I wrote the image it is not correctly displayed. The header Data are ok but the image is not correct.

[image: Bmp image input output]

the rows are correct only the column is some how duplicated and compressed.

My includes are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

This is how I read the pixels

```
void readImage(char *filename, Image *image)
{
    FILE *imageFile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!imageFile)
    {
        perror("ReadImageFileException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fread(&(image->type), sizeof(ImageType), 1, imageFile);
    //validate for correct image type
    if (image->type != BMP_IMAGE_TYPE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%hu", image->type);
        perror("ReadImageTypeException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fread(&(image->header), sizeof(ImageHeader), 1, imageFile);
    fread(&(image->metadata), sizeof(ImageMetadata), 1, imageFile);
    
    // Allocate space for the pixels.
    image->pixels = malloc( image->metadata.height * sizeof(ImageColors *) );
    for(int i = 0; i < image->metadata.height; i++){
        image->pixels[i] = malloc(image->metadata.width * sizeof(ImageColors));
    }
    
    // Read in each pixel
    for (int i = 0; i < image->metadata.height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < image->metadata.width; j++){
            ImageColors px;
            if( fread(&px, sizeof(ImageColors), 1, imageFile) < 1 ) {
                printf("Error while reading bmp pixel.\n");
                return;
            }

            image->pixels[i][j] = px;
        }
    }

    fclose(imageFile);
}
```

This is how I write them.

```
void writeImage(char *filename, Image *image)
{
    FILE *imageFile = fopen(filename, "wb+");
    if (!imageFile)
    {
        perror("WriteImageFileException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t typeWritten = fwrite(&(image->type), sizeof(image->type), 1, imageFile);
    if (typeWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImageTypeException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t headerWritten = fwrite(&(image->header), sizeof(image->header), 1, imageFile);
    if (headerWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImageHeaderException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t metadataWritten = fwrite(&(image->metadata), sizeof(image->metadata), 1, imageFile);
    if (metadataWritten == 0)
    {
        perror("WriteImageMetadataException");
        fclose(imageFile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek(imageFile, image->header.offset, SEEK_SET);
    // Read in each pixel
    for (int i = 0; i < image->metadata.height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < image->metadata.width; j++){
            if( fwrite(&image->pixels[i][j], sizeof(ImageColors), 1, imageFile) < 1 ) {
                printf("Error while wr bmp pixel.\n");
                fclose(imageFile);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

        }
    }

    fclose(imageFile);
}
```

Thank you already in advanced. I only included the Methods that are responsible for reading and writing the bmp because in the future I want to add some other features.

@tshiono Thank you I added you lines into it but if I compare the hex files I can see that the image still has some differences:
[image]
The output image looks still the same.

My Main function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int ch;
    char *inputFile = "sample.bmp";
    char *outputFile = "image-copy.bmp";
    Image image;
    
    // try to use port and password from parameter
    while ( (ch = getopt_long_only(argc, argv, "", long_options, NULL)) != -1 ) {
        switch (ch) {
            case 'i':
                inputFile = optarg;
                break;
            case 'o':
                outputFile = optarg;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    
    printf("input File: %s\n", inputFile);
    
    readImage(inputFile, &image);
    writeImage(outputFile, &image);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fwrite(&bitmapImage, ` ==> `fwrite(bitmapImage, `

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: If the source of data is indeed changed (from undefined behavior to defined), and the result is still the "same result" (literally) then perhaps it would be wise to validate all of your IO operations rather than just assuming they succeed. If this is a real bitmap, i'm curious how you're handling the DIB header and color table as well, because this doesn't seem to show that at all.

Comment: I updated my post. I made some changes now I am able that the result is not only black but it is still not displayed correctly.

Comment: Your update is welcome, but please post the compilable code which includes `main()` function. Cheers.

Comment: @tshiono I added the full Methods and my includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the update.
IMHO the `bmp` file format is *stupidly* designed which includes some
pitfalls causing unexpected behaviors.
You may have found if we put the 2-byte MagicNumber "BM" in the header struct,
most compilers automatically put another 2 bytes for boundary alignment.

Another pitfall is we need to keep the byte count
of a row (line) to be *the multiple of four* for word alignment. Then the
starting addresses of every row is located at the word boundary, although
I'm not sure how much it makes the program run faster.
Anyway if the byte count of the row is NOT the multiple of four
(meaning the *width* is NOT the multiple of four), we need to put extra
dummy bytes for the adjustment at the end of every row. Then would you
please modify your reading/writing functions as:

```
readImage:

    // Read in each pixel
    int padding = image->metadata.width % 4;                  // add this line
    for (int i = 0; i < image->metadata.height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < image->metadata.width; j++){
            ImageColors px;
            if( fread(&px, sizeof(ImageColors), 1, imageFile) < 1 ) {
                printf("Error while reading bmp pixel.\n");
                return;
            }
            image->pixels[i][j] = px;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < padding; j++) getc(imageFile);    // add this line
    }

writeImage:

    // Read in each pixel
    int padding = image->metadata.width % 4;                  // add this line
    for (int i = 0; i < image->metadata.height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < image->metadata.width; j++){
            if( fwrite(&image->pixels[i][j], sizeof(ImageColors), 1, imageFile) < 1 ) {
                printf("Error while wr bmp pixel.\n");
                fclose(imageFile);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < padding; j++) putc(0, imageFile); // add this line
    }
```

where the variable `padding` is the count of byte stuffing which can be
calculated based on the value of `width`.

**[Update]**
Try to add the line:

```
    fseek(imageFile, image->header.offset, SEEK_SET);
```

just before the line:

```
    // Read in each pixel
```

in the `readImage()` as that in `writeImage()`.

**[Explanation]**
There are several versions in `bmp` file format and they have different
header size (which is yet another pitfall):

```
version     header.offset (starting address of pixel data)
BMP v2       54
BMP v3      122
BMP v4      138
```

While your definitions of structs are based on `BMP v2`, the provided
bmp file is created in `BMP v4`. Then it causes the conflicts between
header data and the position of the pixel data. That is why your file
comparison shows the difference.

The viewability of the
collapsed image file will depend on the viewer software. In my environment
there is no problem to view the images.

Ideally we should prepare several types of header structs and use one of them
depending on the version. Practically the extended area contains
less significant data and we may skip them in most cases.

Comment: Thank you I also assumed it has something todo with the padding. But it has no effect if I add the lines still the same result. If I change the module calculation I see it has a different result but with modulo 4 it is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but it sounds strange because I have tested my code changing the input image width with the remainder of the modulo between 0, 1, 2,  and 3, then it works well for any pattern. Can you upload your test image somewhere available? Besides please post your `main()` function even if it contains just `readImage()` and `writeImage()`. It is very crucial to test with the identical code and the identical input to share the problem. That is why I'm asking for your `main()` function again and again. BR.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The link to my image is:
https://i.imgur.com/3K0pr4G.jpg

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but you are uploading the image as `jpg` file, which is meaningless. Please post the `bmp` file so I can directly feed the binary file to your program.  BTW as I'm occupied with my main business for a while, please allow me a while (hopefully less than 24 hours) to come back. BR.

Comment: The website automatically changes it to jpg I use now my google drive to upload it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RVqQoa2aMsRzogFJ8ecuSfV855JrxuwK/view?usp=sharing
hope that's ok

Comment: Thank you for the prompt action. I've successfully downloaded the `bmp` file as is. I'll test the code with the image and will come back before long. Cheers.

Comment: I've updated my answer as `[Update]`, although I'm not sure this is the essential cause why your written image is black.
If it doesn't improve, try to change the image viewer software. At least `display` command, one of `ImageMagick` suite, will work.

Comment: Thank you so so much with the fseek(imageFile, image->header.offset, SEEK_SET); I am finally able to read and write.